# How to replace multiple words in SQLite database using update query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to update records in a database for multiple words in a SQL query, e.g. update (replace word) all 1 to a, 2 to b, 3 to c etc in a query.

I know how to this for single record

```
UPDATE table 
SET column = REPLACE(column, '1', 'a');
```

but how achieve same for multiple words at once?

Comment: Run it 3 times. Or use `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column, '1', 'a'), '2', 'b'), '3', 'c');`.

Comment: i wnat to replace 72 words at same time is there any other way @Turophile

Comment: If you need to do 72 replacements in a single pass, you would have to write yourself a program to read each row, make the changes you require, then update the row.